# Index usage explanation

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Consider this test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dept (deptid integer PRIMARY KEY, deptname TEXT);
CREATE INDEX dept_name_idx on dept(deptname);
```

The `dept` table contains 1000 rows and the `deptname` column contains 10 unique values that are evenly distributed.

Which of the following two sample queries would use the index `dept_deptname_idx`?

1) `SELECT deptid from dept where deptname ='SAPA';`

2) `SELECT deptid from dept where deptname <>'SAPA';`

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

With only *10* distinct values, evenly distributed, chances are that ***neither*** query will use the index. A sequential scan of the table is typically faster than involving any indexes when retrieving more than roughly 5 % of all rows. Exact numbers depend on many details.

Also, 1000 small rows like in your example fit on a hand full of data pages. A sequential scan is hard to beat with such a small table.

With a much bigger table and/or substantially more distinct values in `deptname`, *query 1* would be a candidate for using the index, but not *query 2* (which retrieves most rows and will always use a sequential scan).

To optimize read performance for *query 1* you could then use a multicolumn index on `(deptname, deptid)` - if preconditions for [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) are met.